# Would restoring from Time Machine overwrite iCloud Drive files?

Tags: macos, icloud, time-machine

Just to confirm, restoring macOS from Time Machine wouldn't impact the files currently on iCloud, right? I just want to make sure my iCloud files don't revert to some sort of earlier state from when the backup was created.

Comment: If the backup includes the folders that are synced to iCloud, then yes, it is likely to overwrite them. iCloud will just synchronise whatever files you have.